# Число просмотров, разделитель групп разрядов

Tags: предложение, дефект, статус-отложено

Пока я сюда не заходил, что-то, видимо, изменилось в интерфейсе, и теперь при количестве просмотров темы от тысячи эти самые тысячи отделяются от сотен запятой. А это правильно для английского (не знаю, для каких ещё), но отнюдь не русского языка, где тысячи отделяются пробелом, а дробная часть — запятой (в английском точкой).

Почему так сделали и нельзя ли это исправить?

Comment: Ваш запрос по-прежнему обрабатывается. Приносим извинения за долгое ожидание!

Comment: Ничего, придётся подождать) Спасибо, что сказали!)

Answer (score 0):

Я задал вопрос администраторам сайта и попытаюсь узнать, можно ли изменить способ разделения разрядов.

Изначально Stack Exchange — англоязычная платформа. Думаю, что с этим и связано то, что вы описываете.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Aer! В том-то и дело, что раньше было не так. В любом случае, надеюсь, Вы согласны, что, когда число сочетается с русским словом ("просмотров" в данном случае), писать надо по русским правилам. :)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой да, конечно, мне тоже привычней запись типа 1( )399, без запятой :)